# Best way to avoid StaleElementReferenceException on Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing some tests for a web interface which is constantly refreshing and refreshes at a high rate. What is the best way to avoid getting the StaleElementReferenceException? Usually I would need to check if the page has the element based on ID. If found, then this element is clicked (can be a button, or hyperlink, etc).

EDIT: Code example

```
profile = webui.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Test_string_for_profile')
assert_that(profile, not_none(), 'Profile exists')
webui.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Test_string_for_profile').click()
```

The assertion, which is done via hamcrest, passes. Whenever the third line is executed, the exception is raised. I am aware that the page refreshes quite fast (it has to, and I cannot control how often it refreshes).

Comment: This is really use-case specific. Please provide the code you have so far and, if possible, the link to the webpage you are working with.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a standard try / except block?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from a blog, verify whether it might be useful. Code in C#

```
public static Boolean RetryingFind(By by)
    {
        Boolean result = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while (attempts < 2)
        {
            try
            {
                Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(by);
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
                new WebDriverWait(Drivers._driverInstance, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10));
            }
            attempts++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

In C# we have wait, no idea about phyton

```
new WebDriverWait(Drivers._driverInstance, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(_webElement));
```